# GetModel class with Magento retrieve data based on a mysql field which is not a primary key

Tags: php, sql, magento

I would like to change this snippet to fetch some data from a table, and instead of triggering the primary key(which looks like the default behaviour of the load() function), I would like to trigger another field in my request...How can i do that ?

```
$mytable = Mage::getModel('mytable/mytable')->load($mytable_id)->getData();
```

thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the collection:

```
$mytable = Mage::getModel('mytable/mytable')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('your_attribute_code', 'your_filter_value'); // here you'll get a collection
```

Otherwise:

```
$mytable = Mage::getModel('mytable/mytable')->load('filter_value', 'attribute_code');
```

Comment: Thx, but do you know how to use the sql attribute: "LIKE" with this kind of snippet (the first you gave me) ?

Comment: Here is the sample with LIKE: $mytable = Mage::getModel('mytable/mytable')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('name', array('like' => 'abc%'));

Answer (score 2):

If you use ->getCollection(), you may need to use ->getFirstItem() to get the first item only.

```
$mytable = Mage::getModel('mytable/mytable')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('your_attribute_code', 'your_filter_value')->getFirstItem();
```